# how to hide an ImageView when user clicks on my button.and again show ImageView when same button clicked?

Tags: android

how to hide an ImageView when user clicks on my button.and again show ImageView when same button clicked?

Comment: Show the "codes" you tried if you would like help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code in your project:

```
private ImageView picview;

    //*snip* loads of other code

//Show Image Button
ImageButton show_pic = new ImageButton(this);
show_pic.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
show_pic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(picview.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
         {
         picview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         } 
        else if (picview.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
         {
         picview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }          
        }

});

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
params.topMargin = 10;
params.leftMargin = 10;
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, button2_id);
rl.addView(show_pic, params);

//Imageview loaded from drawable
picview = new ImageView(this);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 400);
params.topMargin = 0;
params.leftMargin = 30;
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, button2_id);
picview.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
picview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
rl.addView(picview, params);

this.setContentView(rl);
```